# Advance syllable counter with php and regex

Tags: php, regex

Im making a syllable counter that hyphenates words with the following parameters

Ex.

Res olu tio n = re-so-lu-tion

Ver sat ile = Ver-sa-til

Ped ago gy = Pe-da-go-gy

Tra nsu bst ant iat ion = tran-sub-stan-ti-a-tion

Ame ric an = Ame-ri-can

Rudimentary = ru-di-men-ta-ry

Hig hli ght = high-light

Im using PHP to code it, so far, im able to break the word down:

```
<?php

$string = 'University';

preg_replace('/tion|[aeiou]/', "-$0", $string);

?>
```

**Output:**
Un-iv-ers-ity

What it needs to do now is read the exceptions. 
Output after the rules are placed in.

1. Uni
2. ver
3. si
4. ty

How would i change the PHP expression to account for the required rules?
Would java script perhaps be a better language?

Answer (score 1):

Since breaking a word into syllables is not something you can express as a "rule", regex is not a good tool (the language doesn't matter). There are too many exceptions! The only reasonable thing will be to create a parser.

That said, for the example you posted above you can do:

```
preg_replace('/tion|Uni|ver|si|ty|[aeiou]/', "-$0", $string);
```

Comment: Hey @alfasin, though I was trying to make a algorithim that would see if any of the individual groups of three words had a pattern.

Comment: @ThelsonRichardson what you are looking for is to build a parser which will contain sets of rules including exceptions. You can't do that using a single regex.

Comment: Basically: break up the word into groups of three characters, see if any of the groups fit the individual parameters, then adjust the words according to the parameters, finally add the preg_replace. where im getting stuck at is checking the individual three letter words for parameters

Comment: Since you refuse to listen - go on and do it the hard way :) good luck!

Comment: @ThelsonRichardson hey, sometimes we *need* to bang our heads against the wall until we get enlightened. Happened to me too many times unfortunately... :)